# How to get text in array between all <span> tag from HTML?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to fetch text in array between all `<span> </span>` tag from HTML, I have tried with this code but it returns only one occurrence :

```
preg_match('/<span>(.+?)<\/span>/is', $row['tbl_highlighted_icon_content'], $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

My HTML:

```
<span>The wish to</span> be unfairly treated is a compromise attempt that would COMBINE attack <span>and innocen</span>ce.  Who can combine the wholly incompatible, and make a unity  of what can NEVER j<span>oin? Walk </span>you the gentle way,
```

My code returns only one occurrence of span tag, but I want get all text from every span tag in HTML in the form of a php array.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1493698)

Comment: I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/34569269/5477982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to switch to [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function

**Code**

```
$row['tbl_highlighted_icon_content'] = '<span>The wish to</span> be unfairly treated is a compromise attempt that would COMBINE attack <span>and innocen</span>ce. Who can combine the wholly incompatible, and make a unity of what can NEVER j<span>oin? Walk </span>you the gentle way,';    

preg_match_all('/<span>.*?<\/span>/is', $row['tbl_highlighted_icon_content'], $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

as you can see now `array` is correctly populated so you can `echo` all your matches

Answer (score 2):

use `preg_match_all()` it's the same, it will return all the occurrences in the $matches array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: One cannot parse HTML with a regex. [ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1493698).

Comment: like everything, it depends on the context, it's up to the programmer to know what does his data looks like, if it's just span tags with no special content inside, I don't see why not

Answer (score 1):

here is code to get all span value in array

```
      $str = "<span>The wish to</span> be unfairly treated is a compromise
attempt that would COMBINE attack <span>and innocen</span>ce. 
Who can combine the wholly incompatible, and make a unity 
of what can NEVER j<span>oin? Walk </span>you the gentle way,";

preg_match_all("/<span>(.+?)<\/span>/is", $str, $matches);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

**you output will be**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => The wish to
            [1] => and innocen
            [2] => oin? Walk 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => The wish to
            [1] => and innocen
            [2] => oin? Walk 
        )

)
```

you can use o or 1 index

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a third-party component, I'd like to show you [Symfony's DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html) component. It 's a very simple way to parse HTML/XHTML/XML files and navigate through the nodes.

You can even use CSS Selectors. Your code would be something like:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$spans = $crawler->filter("span");
echo $spans[1]->getText();;
```

You don't even need to have a full HTML/XML document, if you assign only the `<span>...</span>` part of your code, it'll work fine.